# How to install laravel passpost with authy and guzzle

Tags: php, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport, authy

[image]I have laravel 5.3 version installed ad now I am going to implement OAuth2.0 using [laravel passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport). But When installing laravel/passport=~1.0 , this gives me error for Authy and guzzle about version conflict. I am using authy 2.0 and authy requires guzzle 5.*, if I use passport then passport requires guzzle 6.*. Please resolve issue. Thanks.

Comment: That's a conflict in dependencies between the two. I will raise this with the Authy team, but you might want to try to [fork authy-php](https://github.com/authy/authy-php), which is open source, and update guzzle yourself.